# How to upsample voxels data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, deep-learning

I have voxel data which 32x32x32 in size. I want to upsample the data to 64x64x64.

I'm using the following code to achieve that.

```
import collections
import os
import scipy.io as io
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd


def getVoxelFromMat(path, cube_len=64):

    voxels = io.loadmat(path)
    voxels = np.pad(voxels,(1,1),'constant',constant_values=(0,0))
    if cube_len != 32 and cube_len == 64:
        voxels = nd.zoom(voxels, (2,2,2), mode='constant', order=0)
    return voxels

files = collections.defaultdict(list)
root = ('/home/vkv/Desktop/3dgan_pytorch/3DShapeNets/volumetric_data')

for split in ['train', 'test']:
    #files_list = [f for f in os.listdir(root + '/' + 'car' + '/' + '30/' + split) if f.endswith('.mat')]
    files_list = [f for f in os.listdir(root + '/' + 'car' + '/' + '30/' + split) if f.endswith('.mat')]
    files[split] = files_list

split = 'train'
file_name = files[split][5]
file_path = root + '/' + 'car' + '/' + '30/' + 'train' + '/' + file_name
volume = np.asarray(getVoxelFromMat(file_path, 64),dtype=np.bool)

print(volume)
```

This is the trace stack I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_run.py", line 27, in <module>
    volume = np.asarray(getVoxelFromMat(file_path, 64),dtype=np.bool)
  File "test_run.py", line 13, in getVoxelFromMat
    voxels = nd.zoom(voxels, (2,2,2), mode='constant', order=0)
  File "/home/vkv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/interpolation.py", line 584, in zoom
    raise RuntimeError('input and output rank must be > 0')
RuntimeError: input and output rank must be > 0
```

Is there any other way to upsample and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you looking for a spline-interpolation only? How would you like the new values to be computed?

Comment: I just want the new values to have the of  64x64x64. I am trying  to implement a research and they didn't mention how upsampled the image.

Comment: Your desired array has more elements than the original array. We need to know how you want to generate the new values. Do you want to interpolate between neighboring points? Or do you want to just replicate the original values?

Comment: I fixed the error by changing `voxels = io.loadmat(path)` to `voxels = io.loadmat(path)['instance']`